# Setting border color gives const variables must be initialized with a constant value

Tags: flutter, dart, colors, border, styling

When trying to set BorderSide color like this for a TextField decoration

```
  enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.cyan[900], width: 1.0),
  ),
```

the following error occurs:

[image]

To use this color as a border i copied the color value from the Colors class and added the following code outside of the "function".

```
const borderColor = Color(0xFF006064);
```

and then I can use it like this:

```
 borderSide: BorderSide(color: borderColor, width: 1.0),
```

This feels really hacky. Is there any other way of solving this?

Comment: what about creating a constant class then import the varible from that @Ørjan

Comment: So I guess there is no way of avoiding this "issue". Then this might be a prettier solution yes. Thanks for the help

Comment: I think so,it is better than initializing color in every screen,this way it will be more cleaner@Ørjan

Answer (score 0):

MaterialColor you will get at runtime. So either remove const

```
TextField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.cyan[900]))),
)
```

or create your own global style file for the app and import it from there.

```
const textFieldBorderColor = Color(0xffd6d6d6);
const buttonColor = Color(0xffd5d5d5);
```

you can also create your own palette

Comment: Ok, so the first solution here is the one that gives the error. The second solution works and is the one that i am using now, as describe in the example. But if there is no way around its ok by me.